# Gridview SelectedIndexChanged can not find cell value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I followed this article for key press search in gridview.Everything working fine but I can't find selecterow cell vaule using selectedindexchanged. Still I can fireup the method but can't see value it return only &nbsp.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-with-Paging-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Could you Post some code for Selected Index Changed ?

Comment: Protected Sub gvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim name As String = gvCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
        MsgBox(name)
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

If you using BoundField Column, then

```
string name = YourGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

and for TemplateField Column controls

```
string name = (YourGridView.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblSomeName") as Label).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked. However I get the value by using java script

`$("#<%=gvCustomers.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
                  var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
    $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
        });`